# How much weight can a 2x4 hold

Tags: wood

I wanna make a shelf 16' long 24" deep. I want to be able to put on this about 500lb. The 2x4 will sit on a 4x4 so this is good I think. The question is if a 16' 2x4 will hold it.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's hard to understand what you mean; would you add a diagram to your question?

Comment: Sounds like 2x4 would be mostly unsupported. 500 lbs would be a stretch.

Comment: Just think - 500 lbs is 226 kilograms which is 2 or 3 people.  That's a lot of weight.  But a sketch of what you're trying to achieve would help a lot.  Sounds more like a workbench or table than a shelf.

Comment: i do not think that you can make a 16' shelf with just one 16' 2x4

Comment: Maybe on edge, but I imagine a lot of flex with no center support(s).